# Can providing articles on security improve the perception users have of the security of a website?

Tags: user-behavior, security, content, perception

I also know many who turns off scripting (JavaScript) from running on their system and won't open any website without HTTPS or any security protocol. Whenever I read about Facebook updating its privacy policies and people giving their reviews about it, I feel little less paranoid.

Do articles, reviews or media marketing in general help the user feel safe about their content on a website too?

Comment: Who are you marketing to? They sound like a very paranoid bunch if they refuse to browse any website without https ...

Comment: I believe proper news articles inform users of whatever they need to be informed about so broadly speaking, yes, articles on topic x will improve user perceptions of topic x.

Comment: If they would (articles), it won't be security, just an illusion.

Comment: @J.Gonzalez how come?

Comment: Some Microsoft engineers may write nice articles about security in their blogs. This tells me that there are (some) clever people at Microsoft. This does not make believe that Window$ is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been quite some research on the conversion rates of website using HTTPs (especially the more visible -and more expensive- EV version), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. What do you mean with "perception users have"? How would you measure that?

Also, don't over-estimate that:

1. people read the articles you write on security. I expect visual things like secure site seals to be more effective.
2. everyone knows what HTTPs does. I hardly think that the average user can explain why it's important. What's more: I think it's even less likely they will understand what part exactly it protects (e.g.: using the same password everywhere because "the site uses HTTPs so it doesn't matter").

Comment: What is EV version supposed to mean ?

Comment: Also don't over-estimate that everyone knows how to write HTTPS. ;-)

Comment: Extended Validation. It's the SSL certificate that will make browsers show the pretty (and trustworthy) green bar containing the name of the holder of the certificate :)